# Perform sum when multiple conditions required are in another table?

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the total count of how many users in df1 meet conditions specified in df2, but keep getting an error message.

df1 looks like this:

```
    id  step1          step2
    1   session_start  NA
    2   session_start  NA
    3   session_start  sign_up
    4   session_start  sign_up
    5   session_start  sign_up
    6   sign_up        session_start

df1 <- Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  6 obs. of  3 variables:
    $ id   : chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
    $ step1: chr  "session_start" "session_start" "session_start" "session_start" ...
    $ step2: chr  NA NA "sign_up" "sign_up" ..
```

df2 looks like this:

```
    step1          step2         count
    session_start  sign_up       0
    sign_up        in_screen     0
    in_screen      click_banner  0
    session_stop   session_stop  0

df2 <- structure(c("session_start", "sign_up", "0", "sign_up", 
"in_screen", "0", "in_screen", "click_banner", "0", "session_stop", 
"session_stop", "0", .Dim = c(3L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("step1", "step2", 
"count"), NULL))
```

In the column `df2$count`, I would like to show how many (sum of) users completed `df2$step1` and `df2$step2` in that order. In the sample code above, the first row in `df2$count` would output **3**, as **3** users in df1 completed `session_start` as `df1$step1` and `sign_up` as `df1step2`.

### Previous Attempts

When I try doing this manually using this code, everything works fine:

```
count <- sum(df1$step1 == "session_start" & df1$step2 == "sign_up", na.rm = TRUE)
```

However, when I replace "session_start" and "sign_up" with dynamic values, I get the error that "Error in test8$step1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors":

```
df2$count <- sum(df1$step1 == df2$step1 & df1$step2 == df2$step2, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I tried replacing "$" with "[]", but still get "Error: Columns `session_start`, `sign_up`, `in_screen`, `click_banner`, `session_stop` not found":

```
df2[count] <- sum(df1[step1] == df2[step1] & df1[step2] == df2[step2], na.rm = TRUE)
```

### Ideal response:

I'd love to be able to add the extra column to the data as shown below. Are you able to help? Many thanks in advance if so!

```
    step1          step2         count
    session_start  sign_up       3
    sign_up        in_screen     0
    in_screen      click_banner  0
    session_stop   session_stop  0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>%
  group_by(step1, step2) %>%
  mutate(count = sum(step1 == df1$step1 & step2 == df1$step2, na.rm = TRUE))
## A tibble: 4 x 3
## Groups:   step1, step2 [4]
#  step1         step2        count
#  <chr>         <chr>        <int>
#1 session_start sign_up          3
#2 sign_up       in_screen        0
#3 in_screen     click_banner     0
#4 session_stop  session_stop     0
```

Note that instead of `mutate` you can also use `summarise` but the order of the output rows will be different.

Comment: Thank you! I think there is actually a problem with my data structure as when I try to perform this solution I get this error: "Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'character')". I have added more info about the data structure to the original question.

Comment: @FPL `df2` is an object of class `"matrix"`. Try `as.data.frame(df2) %>% etc`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `mapply` and calculate number of `step1` and `step2` values completed in `df1`.

```
df2$count <- mapply(function(x, y) 
    sum(df1$step1 == x & df1$step2 == y, na.rm = TRUE), df2$step1, df2$step2)


df2
#          step1        step2 count
#1 session_start      sign_up     3
#2       sign_up    in_screen     0
#3     in_screen click_banner     0
#4  session_stop session_stop     0
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), 
step1 = c("session_start", "session_start", "session_start", 
 "session_start", "session_start", 
 "sign_up"), step2 = c(NA, NA, "sign_up", "sign_up", "sign_up", 
"session_start")), .Names = c("id", "step1", "step2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(step1 = c("session_start", "sign_up", "in_screen", 
"session_stop"), step2 = c("sign_up", "in_screen", "click_banner", 
"session_stop")), .Names = c("step1", "step2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks! Very simple and elegant, I love it. Unfortunately, I still get the same error though. Maybe it has to do with how df2 is structured? When I run str(df2), I get: str(df2)
 chr [1:3, 1:36] "session_start" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "step1" "step2" "count"
  ..$ : NULL

Comment: @FPL not sure. Can you update your `dput(df1)` and `dput(df2)` in the question because it works on the sample data which I am using.

Comment: Thank you! I have added information about the data structure. I am quite new to R so probably the error comes from in there somewhere :-)

Comment: @FPL Thank you, it looks like your `df2` is list. Instead of `str(df2)` can you run `dput(df2)` and update the output?

Comment: Again, many thanks! I have updated with dput(df2) in the question (I tried updating df1 as well but it filled up my console ':-) )